# How to cleanup a text file to remove punctuation except @?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

new to coding and I was wondering if anyone is willing to help out. Currently I was given a task to create a program that reads a file, and reports back certain information about that file. Particularly I'm stuck in a program that wants me to be able to search via username. For this I was asked to cleanup the text file, and remove all punctuation except @. So far this is all I have and I'm not sure where to edit my program:

```
def cleanedup(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    cleantext = ''
    for character in s.lower():
        if character in alphabet:
            cleantext += character
        else:
            cleantext += ' '
    return cleantext
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I'm pretty sure this can be made shorter, but please provide feedback based on this. I'm not looking for just an answer, but an understanding on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can cleanup your `cleanedup` code using `string.punctuation`:

```
import string

def cleanedup(s):
    return ''.join([x for x in s if x not in string.punctuation or x == '@'])

print(cleanedup('ag,v,bv_@gmail.com'))
# agvbv@gmailcom
```

`string.punctuation` holds a string of common punctuation characters. We instruct to take not these punctuation characters except if it is a `'@'`.

---

If you would like a corrected version of your code, you might want to add a condition more to handle `'@'`:

```
def cleanedup(s):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    cleantext = ''
    for character in s.lower():
        if character in alphabet or character == '@':
            cleantext += character
        else:
            cleantext += ''
    return cleantext
```